# CSS Specificity Body - Form

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have several pages and a single external style sheet.  The CSS file has the following:

```
body {
    /*Set background image*/
    background: url("../img/background/main.jpg");
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

body form{
    border: double;
}
```

According to what I have been learning is that *body form* would be more specific and should show the double line border around all the elements of type form inside of body.

However, in testing it is not unless I move it above the CSS *body* {} selector meaning that the body selector in the CSS file is overriding the *body form*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's being overridden?  There's not even a `border` rule in `body`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I assumed it would default to no boder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `body form` would take precedence over `form`, but the problem is in the border declaration.  When specifying the values for the border property you should also include the borders width and color as well as the style.

```
border: double 3px #000;
```

this would set the elements border to the style of double, a width of 3px, and a color of black.

Make a note that when using border-style double the minimum border-width to make both borders visible is 3px.

Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bKQkJ/).

Answer (score 0):

For double border you can use border and outline.

**Example**

```
body form {
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    outline: solid 2px #888;
    outline-offset: -5px;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qvb2Y/4/)

Comment: So the form cannot use the double border?